# 500 Internal Server Error - Misconfigured Website

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-500

I am uploading a website to a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS for the first time. I am using Apache 2.4.7, mod_wsgi, and Django 1.8.5. I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I cannot figure out if the problem is in my wsgi file or configuration or my Django configuration.

Apache Error Log:

```
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:14.734974 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 28996:tid 139939323643776] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:15.751172 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29181:tid 139688285566848] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:15.751270 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29181:tid 139688285566848] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.996550 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975] mod_wsgi (pid=29185): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.996694 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.996935 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997146 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997163 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997291 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997305 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997361 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]     sys.exc_info()[2])
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997371 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997384 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]     module = import_module(module_path)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997389 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997425 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975]     __import__(name)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:19.997447 2015] [:error] [pid 29185:tid 139688073475840] [client 107.143.109.119:50975] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.security: "No module named security"
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201372 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976] mod_wsgi (pid=29184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'., referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201446 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201468 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201575 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]     self.load_middleware(), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201587 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201699 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201713 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201765 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]     sys.exc_info()[2]), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201775 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201798 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]     module = import_module(module_path), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201806 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201845 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976]     __import__(name), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:20.201869 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688190367488] [client 107.143.109.119:50976] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.security: "No module named security", referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.650853 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978] mod_wsgi (pid=29184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.650936 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.650987 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651044 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651062 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651083 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651094 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651111 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]     sys.exc_info()[2])
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651119 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651131 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]     module = import_module(module_path)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651140 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651154 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978]     __import__(name)
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.651184 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688107046656] [client 107.143.109.119:50978] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.security: "No module named security"
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719625 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977] mod_wsgi (pid=29184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'., referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719704 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719756 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719834 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]     self.load_middleware(), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719855 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719878 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719890 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719911 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]     sys.exc_info()[2]), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719921 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719958 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]     module = import_module(module_path), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719971 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module, referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.719989 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977]     __import__(name), referer: http://MY_IP/
[Tue Dec 15 19:57:22.720022 2015] [:error] [pid 29184:tid 139688098653952] [client 107.143.109.119:50977] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.security: "No module named security", referer: http://MY_IP/
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/MYSITE')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MYSITE.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName MYSITEinc.com
        ServerAlias www.MYSITEinc.com

        ServerAdmin email@site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/MYSITE

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/MYSITE/MYSITE>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        Alias /static /var/www/MYSITE/static
        <Directory /var/www/MYSITE/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular

    # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ‘KEY’

DEBUG = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

ADMINS = ((‘Name’), ‘name@site.com’)
MANAGERS = ((‘Name’), ‘name@site.com’)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    ‘IP_ADDRESS’, ‘MYSITE.com',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web',
    'bootstrap3',
    'feedparser',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = ‘MYSITE.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MYSITE.wsgi.application'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'web.User'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'MYSITE',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': ‘PASSWORD’,
        'HOST': ‘IP_ADDRESS’,
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

CONN_MAX_AGE = None

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/MYNAME/MYSITE/'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MYSITE@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘PASSWORD’
```

If anyone has suggestions or solutions, can you please post them?

Comment: Do you have this`SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` middleware added in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, I have it in Middleware_Classes = ( ... 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',               ... )

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed? Could it be that you are loading wrong version of django?

Comment: The django and python versions are correct.

Comment: Can you post your settings, sensitive bits removed? Or just your middleware settings?

Comment: I updated the post with my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have your middleware in the wrong order.

Try putting your session middleware BEFORE your auth middleware (error in your logs indicates this problem).

[The Django documentation covers middleware ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering) as well.

Comment: This did not solve the main error but some of my Middleware was out of order so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you try removing `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',` from your middleware classes?

Comment: I updated the error log with your suggestion completed.